# SugarCRM: Create NOTE with Attachment without SOAP?

Tags: class, attachment, sugarcrm

I've got this custom button on Lead Editview that when clicked on generates (via AJAX) an invoice number and a PDF bearing the same number.

In the next step, the routine uses SOAP to loopback to Sugar and creates a Note (along with the PDF as attachment).

My question is can I avoid this SOAP call and use some other internal mechanism / classes to do the same? Something along the lines of

```
$invoice = new Note();
$invoice->create(....);
...
```

Is this possible? I couldn't find any documentation anywhere... all roads seem to point to SOAP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Ajax call is performing a db update/save operation, then you could look into using a `after_save` logic hook.

**EDIT:** for eg: you could try out this code, have a look at the code in `<sugar_root>/modules/Notes/Note.php`

```
$note = new Note();
$note->modified_user_id = $current_user->id;
$note->created_by = $current_user->id;
$note->name = 'New';
$note->parent_type = "Accounts";
$note->parent_id = $bean->parent_id;
$note->description = $bean->description;
$note->save();
```

As far as attachment goes, it's a bit tricky. Sugar expects the attachment to be a upload_file object. Have a look at the code in `<sugar_root>/modules/Notes/controller.php` the function `action_save()` and `<sugar_root>/include/upload_file.php`

**HACK:** this is not the correct way but it works. With a slight modification to the code above and cunning use of the `move` function , you could make the attachment work. Sugar stores the attachments in `cache/upload` folder with the ID of the note created.

```
$note->filename = "Yourfilename.txt" //your file name goes here
$note->file_mime_type = "text/plain"  // your file's mime type goes here
$new_note_id = $note->save();

move(your_file_location, cache/upload/$new_note_id)
//don't add a extension to cache/upload/$new_note_id
```

HTH

P.S: untested code

Comment: Hello Anand, I know about after_save and am using it in several places. However, in this case I'm trying to figure out if a NOTE can actually be created by instantiating a NOTE object and using any members methods to create the note and attach a file to it - instead of doing it via SOAP.

Comment: Thanks Anand. Missed out on your update. Will try and get back to you ASAP. Code looks promising :)

Comment: Tried the part upto creating the note. Works like a CHARM and saves one whole extra SOAP round-trip. :D Thanks man. Will play around with the file moving and let you know.

Comment: PERFECT! Your file hack worked a 100% - without having to mess around with any of the upload_file routines. Cheers!

Comment: A top-up question, if you are still around. Do you think it's possible to follow the same approach to create a DRAFT Email containing this file as attachment?

Comment: Here's a link that might shed some light on the Email thingum. http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/showthread.php?t=45272

Answer (score 0):

Do this on controller.php

```
 foreach ( $_FILES as $file ) {
        for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count( $file[ 'name' ] ) ; $i++ ) {
            $fileData = file_get_contents( $file[ 'tmp_name' ][ $i ] );   
            $fileTmpLocation = $file[ 'tmp_name' ][ $i ];     
            $fileMimeType = mime_content_type( $file[$i] );        
            $fileInfo = array( 'name' => $file[ 'name' ][ $i ], 'data' => $fileData, 'tmpLocation' =>$fileTmpLocation, 'mimeType' => $fileMimeType );
            
            array_push( $files, $fileInfo );
        }
    }

    $this->guardarNotas($this->bean->id,$files);
}
```

And this is the function to save Notes with attachment:

```
 private function guardarNotas($case_id,$files){

    foreach($files as $file){
        $noteBean = BeanFactory::newBean('Notes');
        $noteBean->name = $file['name'];
        $noteBean->parent_type = "Cases";
        $noteBean->parent_id = $case_id;

        $noteBean->filename = $file["name"]; 
        $noteBean->file_mime_type = $file["mimeType"];
        

        $noteBean->save();

        move_uploaded_file($file["tmpLocation"], "upload/".$noteBean->id);                       

    }

}
```